# Unable to connect AWS IOT with AWS Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, iot

I am new to AWS and IOT. I am trying to connect my raspberry pi with AWS IOT and from there I am trying to push the data to Elasticsearch.

I have managed to to connect raspberry pi with AWS IOT and able to see the data I have sent from Raspberry pi through "Test" in IOT console.

I have created topic rule and configured elasticsearch endpoint, added IAM role.

In rule destination i've entered the elasticsearch endpoint and created it but it shows the following message.

"Awaiting confirmation. Confirmation message sent on 2020-11-26T11:22:55.602Z. The destination responded with HTTP status code - 405."

I am unable see any message in cloudwatch logs to get the token and confirm the destination.

My elastic search access policy is set to open access to domain and the iot policy is as follows

{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": "iot:*",
"Resource": "*"
}
]
}

I dont know whether I am doing it correct. Please help me to confirm the destination and stream data to elastic search.

Thanks in advance,